# SQL Server: Cannot Insert Default Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I've created a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Users] 
(
    [UserID_PK] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Email] NVARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    [Username] NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    [Salt] NVARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    [Token] NVARCHAR(200),
    [DateCreated] DATETIME DEFAULT (GETDATE()) NOT NULL
);
```

Every time my API creates a record, it returns this message. I am not sure why the default value isn't being inserted instead of NULL. I've tried `GETDATE()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DateCreated'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Answer (score 4):

**The root cause:**
The problem is not with how you defined `default` for the *DateCreated* column on the table it's with your insert statement.

**How to implicitly use default value:**
If you want the `default` value to be used make sure to not include the column(s) defined with `default` in the `insert` statement your using. Example: `insert into dbo.Users(Name) select 'someName'` Your column(s) defined with `default` will get the default value implicitly if you don't explicitly include it as a column in the `insert` statement when inserting row(s).

**Why you are getting the error:**
You are getting this Error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DateCreated'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

because you're explicitly including the `DateCreated` column in your insert statement and not providing a value, something like: `insert into dbo.Users(Email,DateCreated) select 'someName'`

**Resolution:**
To resolve this provide a value for the column like this:  `insert into dbo.Users(Email,DateCreated) select 'someEmail',getdate()` or remove `DateCreated` from the insert and it will implicitly get the default value even if you don't include it as a column when you insert values for other columns on the row. You can even hard code a string literal date value `'2020-08-22 19:05:00'` to set a specific date time if you don't want to use `getdate()` or another similar date function.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you have two options for inserting a default value.  One is to leave out the column:

```
insert into users (email, username, password, salt, token)
    values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

The second is to use the [`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) keyword:

```
insert into users (email, username, password, salt, token, dateCreated)
    values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, default);
```

`NULL` is not a synonym for `DEFAULT`.

I should point out that there is actually a third way.  That requires navigating the metadata tables to look up the default value for a column.  As a general rule, that approach is not useful.  On occasion, it can be quite helpful.

Comment: I'm developing software since more than 12 years now. I never seen sth like `default` in the values of `insert into`.. just facing it now.. didn't `null` work as default-value in the past? I'm pretty sure it did - or did it just in some database-systems? or did I sleep the last 12 years..? :D

Comment: @matthaisburger … This answer is specific to SQL Server